# Java: What's the point of Char to Int conversion and then comparison Int to Char? And why does this work?

Tags: java, char, int, switch-statement

I'm reading Java-book. There is a code that I don't get.  Why are we saving result in INT if we need to compare to CHAR anyway? And why does this work properly?

```
public static **char** getChar() throws IOException
  {
  String s = getString();
  return s.charAt(0);
  }
**int** choice = getChar();

switch(**choice**)
  {
            case **'s'**: {}
            case 'r': {}
            case 'n': {}
            case 'g': {}                   
            case 'b': {}                   
            case 'a': {}                  
            case 'd': {}                 
            default:  {}
  }
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not the author of your Java book.

Comment: Probably that example was lifted from C, where an expression used in a switch statement must have an integral or enumerated type.  There's no reason to do that in Java.

Comment: `char` is an integral type, and widening conversions are legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between using `char` and `int` literals in the switch:

```
public static void withCharLiteral() {
  int choice = getChar();
  switch (choice) {
    case 's':
      break;
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
  public static void withCharLiteral();
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method getChar:()C
       3: istore_0
       4: iload_0
       5: lookupswitch  { // 1
                   115: 24
               default: 24
          }
      24: return
```

vs with an `int` literal:

```
public static void withIntLiteral() {
  int choice = getChar();
  switch (choice) {
    case 115:
      break;
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
  public static void withIntLiteral();
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method getChar:()C
       3: istore_0
       4: iload_0
       5: lookupswitch  { // 1
                   115: 24
               default: 24
          }
      24: return
```

All `char` can be converted to `int`, even the ones you use in switch cases. As such, it is just a question of preference/convenience/readability as to whether you use the char or int literal form.